# how to detect the device using libqmi-glib

Tags: c

I am learning how to use QMI to talk with the Sierra Wireless Card. I am looking through the libqmi-glib reference on its website and I just want to do some basic actions with the device.

My question is that how I can detect the new device when is plugged in?

I check the reference and find a method:

```
void qmi_device_new(GFile *file, GCancellable *cancellable, 
                         GAsyncReadyCallback callback, gpointer user_data)
```

It seems to be used for detecting the new device but I even don't know what does the parameters mean...like where can I get the GFile and how can I invoke the QMI port and send the request...

Is there any expert to provide me some ideas or examples? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The GFile that you need to pass should already have the path of the device to use. libqmi expects the /dev/cdc-wdm devices exposed by the qmi_wwan kernel driver, so you can for example do:

```
#include <libqmi-glib.h>

GFile *f;

f = g_file_new_for_path ("/dev/cdc-wdm0");
qmi_device_new (f, NULL, (GAsyncReadyCallback)device_new_ready, NULL);
g_object_unref (f)
```

You of course will need to have a device_new_ready() method that calls qmi_device_new_finish(), and a main loop running. If you want to see a 'real world' example of usage, you can check the [qmicli](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libqmi/tree/src/qmicli/qmicli.c) sources.

If you want to get **notified** of new QMI devices being plugged in your system, you can use the [GUdev](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/gudev/) library and listen for changes of devices in the "usb" or "usbmic" subsystems, where the driver managing the parent device is "qmi_wwan".